# f.write() function is not working in python since this morning

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I am using **Python 2.7** and the function, `f.write()` is not working. A part of my code is given below.

Please suggest if any packages need to be installed.

```
for item in data1['OperationalTimes']['airportResources']: 
        with open("airportResources_details.txt",'a') as f: -- code works fine till here when i try to "print data1"
            f.write(item['arrivalTerminal']+'\n') -- this line is not getting through
```

Comment: And what happens when you "try to `print data1`"?

Comment: print data1 gives me desired result. Its only when I try writing it in a file, the function does not respond. Above all, this was working 2 days back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, you can avoid the performance drain of opening and closing the file for every single item, by simply changing the order of things:

```
with open("airportResources_details.txt",'a') as f:
    for item in data1['OperationalTimes']['airportResources']: 
        f.write(item['arrivalTerminal']+'\n')
```

Beyond that, you may want to check the usual suspects, like ensuring you're running in the correct directory. For example, use `os.system("pwd")` for getting the current working directory (on a UNIX-like platform).

Or temporarily changing the file specifier to something like `/tmp/xyzzy.txt` and seeing if that gets created in the right place.

Or temporarily changing it to use `print` rather than `f.write` to see if it comes out on standard output.

Comment: I have tried `print data1` and output comes fine. Only when I attempt to write it in a txt file, the `f.write()` does not work. And writing the data in a file is my prime target.
I tried the code you gave above, and it's still give me same results. I suspect If **Python 2.7** has undergone any package level change.

Comment: @Manish, that code snippet I gave was to make what you have more efficient, it wasn't to fix the core problem. To fix the core problem, you need to investigate all my _other_ points.